# For each unique value in pandas dataframe column, make a go.Figure and scatter t

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have a dataframe somewhat like so:

Date | Category | Number | Number2 | Etc. |

I want to take every unique value in Category, and plot a line graph with the first Number column, with Date as the X axis. For now I was thinking of doing indiviudal go.Figures, but I may condense it into one graph if it isn't too noisy.

First I tried taking a list of uniques with:

```
listOfUniques = df['Category'].unique()
```

and passing that to a for loop, but I quickly realised that was the wrong approach. Then I tried to make a dictionary based on the unique values:

```
df1 = dict()
for k, v in df.groupby('Category'):
df1[k] = v
```

but I also could not figure out how to then take the dictionary entries and make a plot for each entry, and it seems like there must be a simpler operation for querying the original df. Let me know if I can give any other information that would help with an answer.

Also, I will probably want to evaluate the numbers conditionally as the percent of some other number in some other column, such that if it is not above, say, 25% of value Y, do not make the plot. I will probably add Y as another column in the original df. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think your first approach is too bad---probably not the most efficient method, but can definitely get the job done.

```
    listOfUniques = df['Category'].unique()
    for unique in listOfUniques.values():
        tempdf = df[ df['Category'] == unique]
        plt.plot(tempdf['Date'], tempdf['Number'], label=unique)
        ###Uncomment this line if you don't want them all on the same graph. 
        ###plt.show()
    plt.show()
```

Depending on what your data is like this is a viable method.

Comment: Thanks! This does exactly what I want. How would I pass this to a go.Figure scatter though? I have tried without luck.

Comment: https://plotly.com/python/creating-and-updating-figures/. Just looked through this and It gives pretty straight forward examples.

Something along the lines of:
fig = px.scatter(df, x={x}, y={y}, color="species",
                 title={title)

Then plug this into the for-loop instead of the plt.plot:
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x= tempdf['Date'],
        y=tempdf['Number'],
        mode="lines")
)